# Is there a way to displace or randomize shape of metaballs? Achieve effect like this?

Tags: materials, particles, eevee-render-engine, meta-objects

Ok, Im trying to create a cartoonish effect in eevee somewhat like the fire and the energy ball by Violet here -

[image]

Specifically what Ive tried so far (to mimic specifically the distortion on the energy ball by Violet) is a particle system emitting metaballs of various sizes and at various velocities, so they merge together to create an oddly shaped blob:

[image]

Issue from here is, I want the sharp edges/additional distortion that the above example incorporates. Mine is pretty uniform just spitting out meta balls.

How can I distort a meta ball particle system or achieve this effect otherwise? I cant apply a displace modifier to the meta ball so I dont know where to go next.